# Radio button like DB column

Tags: sqlite, database-design

In my application, stored

```
ColumnName    DataType
====================
country       text
selected      boolean
```

like this. Only one country can select at specified time. Is there any possibility in SQLite, or any ideas?

If i select another country the selected value is `true` on the selected country only. Other country selected column automatically set as `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking the database to do what your application should do.

In your database, you have a country table.

Your application selects one of the country rows.  That's the one and only one country that your application uses.

To switch to another country, your application selects a different row.